Form of elliptic curve where torsion of order 4 is apparent
While studying elliptic curves, I came upon this form for an elliptic curve with a point of order $3$: $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyzp$. Unlike other forms of elliptic curves, the order $3$ torsion is apparent: Given any solution $(x,y,z)$ you can cyclically permute the coordinates.
My question is: Is there a similar way to represent elliptic curves so that that torsion of order $4$ is apparent?
This would probably have to be in $P^3$ space rather than $P^2$ as in the order 3 case.
My attempts so far:

Intersect a cyclically symmetric degree $3$ equation with the equation $w+x+y+z=0$. Unfortunately, all such equations (e.g. $w^3x+x^3y+y^3z+z^3w$) have $x+z$ as a factor once you force $w+x+y+z=0$. I tried to get around this by trying a higher degree equation, but degree $4$ equations don't have this property, and degree $5$ and higher doesn't seem to have other possible factors drop out that could turn it into an elliptic curve.

Intersect two quadrics. This seemed more promising, and I could take the equations $xy+wz=u(wx+wy+xz+yz)$ and $xy+wz=v(w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2)$. Solutions are invariant under the dihedral group of order 8 (expressed as the symmetry group of the square with $w,x,z,zy$ as the vertices in that order). However, this turned out to be highly singular, and once the equations were combined, it would factor into two conics.


Is there a way to write a symmetric form of an elliptic curve of a point of order 4? Specifically, in such a way that the equations themselves are invariant under a cyclic permutation of the coordinates?

I tried it for order 5, but you need three equations, and if you take the only linear cyclic invariant ($v+w+x+y+z=0$), then there are only two linearly independent quadratic cyclic invariants (as the third option automatically became 0). Setting them both equal to zero forces everything to be zero. So it seems to be hard for any order above three...

You might find Tate normal form useful. See this post, along with Lemma 2.1 (p. 3) of the referenced article. The torsion isn't visible just through permuting coordinates, but the torsion point is apparent, at least.

Yeah the Tate normal form is quite useful, especially because the torsion generator is (0,0), it just isn't at all obvious that the point has a given order (other than that you can force it to with the modular equation)

The answer is yes (up to replacing your words "cyclic permutation of coordinates" with "linear automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$), you have noticed a quite interesting and fundamental lemma in the construction of modular curves which I think is essentially due to Klein.

Lemma. Let $n \geq 3$ be an odd integer and let $E/k$ be an elliptic curve ($k$ of characteristic coprime to $n$). Then there exists a curve $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ such that $\mathcal{E}$ is isomorphic to $E$ and translation by an $n$-torsion point $P \in E$ is given by a linear automorphism of the ambient projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

The sketchy proof of the lemma goes as follows. Let $O \in E(k)$ be the identity and  consider the divisor $D = nO$. By the Riemann--Roch theorem the dimension of the Riemann--Roch space $H^0(E, D)$ is $n$. Thus choosing a basis $x_0, ..., x_{n-1} \in H^0(E, D)$ we obtain a morphism $\varphi \colon E \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. One can easily check that $\varphi$ separates points and tangent directions, so is an isomorphism onto its image -- call that $\mathcal{E}$.
But now a hyperplane section $H$ of $\mathcal{E}$ is linearly equivalent to $D = nO$, and you then use this to show that translation by $P$ must act linearly on the ambient space (it must preserve $H$ as $H \sim D \sim \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} [mP]$ as divisors).
The curve $\mathcal{E}$ is often called the elliptic normal curve of degree $n$. In your example, this is with $n = 3$ and the linear action is the cyclic permutation of coordinates of the plane cubic model you present (which is the universal curve over $X(3)$ btw).
When $n = 4$ this is the embedding of an elliptic curve as a quadric intersection in $\mathbb{P}^3$. More generally $\mathcal{E}$ is a (non-complete) intersection of quadratic forms for all $n \geq 4$.

To elaborate on the case $n = 4$. We have the universal curve over $X(4)$ given by the equations
$$ x^2 + z^2 = \lambda yw $$
$$ y^2 + w^2 = \lambda xz $$
in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Actually, this is the only case where the lemma above works for $n$ even (because of $2$ things).
Note that your model for $n = 3$ and this one for $n = 4$ are not "universal with an $n$-torsion point". It's probably a useful exercise to work out the embedding for the universal curve over $X_1(3)$ and $X_1(4)$.

Could you give an example (or even the general form) of the quadric intersection for n=4?

@ThomasBlok see the edit
